# NSViewController for each row in View-Based NSTableView?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsview, nsviewcontroller

Usual good practice in Cocoa dictates that each `NSView` should have its own `NSViewController` as its owner.  Should this apply to each row of a View-Based `NSTableView` and, if so, what's a good strategy for initializing and caching these NSViewControllers?

Answer (score 2):

In most cases this would be overkill.  No need for *every* `NSView` to have a controller.  What about views which have no relationship with the model layer - in which case a mediator/controller would be unnecessary?  In a large table, this would lead to a proliferation of controller objects that are likely unneeded.

I would take a close look at the [TableViewPlayground](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project available in the documentation.  Notice in that project how Apple uses the various views that comprise the rows.  In particular, focus on the `ATComplexTableViewController` class and its associated nib file.  Here, the `dataSource` for the table view returns views for which the `dataSource` itself acts as the mediator between the view and the model.